# Figure and Table Caption Delimiters

Tags: captions, delimiters

I am using the memoir class for a thesis document.  I need to use different delimiters for the figures ( Fig 1.1, ) and table (Table 1.1. ) captions.  I tried using 
\captiondelim{, } 
However that changes all the delimiters to ','.  I also tried creating a new caption style with \captiondelim{. } for use with the table.  However doing this makes the list of tables create the correct table number with an empty caption ( something like 1.1. empty ) in the toc.  I am not sure whats the best way to do this.

Thank you

Edit: I am adding the minimum working code for this.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captiondelim{, } % change default delimiter


\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \captionnamefont{\scshape} 
    \changecaptionwidth
    \captionwidth{0.9\linewidth}
    \captiondelim{.\:} 
    \indentcaption{0.75cm}
    \captionstyle[\centering]{}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \caption{#2}\else \caption[#1]{#2}
} 


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\centering
Space for Fig 1
\mycaption{Figure} 
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering 
Space for Table 1
\caption{Table} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The behavior you site does not match the manual.  Perhaps you are loading a package which redefines \@makecaption.  Submit a Minimal Working Example which displays the problem, starting with \documentclass all the way to \end{document} (please, NOT your thesis!).

Comment: Hi @adi, welcome to Tex.SE! Please share your minimum working example code for this. This will help you to get better answers, and sometimes solve your own problem even before you get an answer from this platform.

Answer (score 1):

`\captiondelim` will change the delimiter for all captions, but you want different delimiters for figure and table captions (I have no idea why; is it one of those strange rules promoted by thesis folk who have no idea about good typography?)

Essentially you have to have two different captioning styles, as in the MWE below.

```
% capdelimprob.tex SE 520197 Different delimiters for figures and tables

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captiondelim{. } % change default delimiter
\makeatother
\newcommand{\figcaption}[2][\@empty]{% another delimiter for figures
  \captiondelim{, }%
  \ifx \@empty#1 \caption{#2} \else \caption[#1]{#2} }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
A FIGURE
\figcaption{Figure caption} % special caption
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering 
A TABLE
\caption{Table caption} % regular caption
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

To begin I used `\captiondelim` to give the delimiter you wanted for tables. Then I defined a new kind of caption for tables that used the delimiter you wanted for them. See **10.5 Captions** in the documentation (`> texdoc memoir`) for more information.

Comment: Yes I need to use a comma as a delimiter for the figures but that does not look good with the tables and code examples I have so I need to use the different delimiters.  I have added a picture of the problem with the table of contents not updating to the correct caption ( the delimiter is correct).  The same thing happened with the \figcaption too.